# How to get array of values from an associative arrays?

Tags: php

How can I get an array of values from an associative array ?

Associate array Example:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => 1
            [1] => 2
            [2] => 3
        )
    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => 4
            [1] => 5
            [2] => 6
        )
    [2] => Array
        (
            [0] => 7
        )
)
```

Desired Output

```
Array
(1,2,3,4,5,6,7)
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Not sure it'll suit you, as it's PHP >= 5.3 only, but here's a possible solution, **using [`array_walk_recursive`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-walk-recursive.php) and a closure** *(see [Anonymous functions](http://fr.php.net/manual/en/functions.anonymous.php))* :

```
$array = array(
    array(1, 2, 3), 
    array(4, 5, 6), 
    array(7), 
);

$result = array();
array_walk_recursive($array, function ($value, $key) use (& $result) {
    $result[] = $value;
});
var_dump($result);
```

And the result :

```
array
  0 => int 1
  1 => int 2
  2 => int 3
  3 => int 4
  4 => int 5
  5 => int 6
  6 => int 7
```

Basicaly, the closure is the only way I got this to work : it's used to import the `$result` variable, by reference, into the anonymous function.

---

And, just to post it, the only I got this working for PHP 5.2 *(i.e. not using a closure)* is with this :

```
$result = array();
array_walk_recursive($array, 'my_func', & $result);
var_dump($result);

function my_func($value, $key, & $result) {
    $result[] = $value;
}
```

Which works too -- but raises a warning :

```
Deprecated: Call-time pass-by-reference has been deprecated
```

Unfortunatly, I didn't find a way of getting this to work without passing `$result` by reference at call-time :-(

*(Maybe someone else has an idea, about how to do that ?)*

Comment: +1. Although I have an answer that doesn't use closures, this was my first thought of how to do it. Answering PHP questions will be more fun when PHP5.3 becomes more common.

Comment: @Yacoby : PHP 5.3 FTW ! *(anonymous functions and closures are one thing I would really like to be able to use, at work... But we're using PHP 5.2 ;-( )*

Answer (score 1):

Do an array_merge() on each separate member.

```
$test = Array
(
    "0" => Array
        (
            0 => 1,
            1 => 2,
            2 => 3,
        ),
    "1" => Array
        (
            0 => 4,
            1 => 5,
            2 => 6,
        ),
    "2" => Array
        (
            0 => 7,
        )
);

print_r(array_merge($test[0],$test[1],$test[2]));
// Array ( [0] => 1 [1] => 2 [2] => 3 [3] => 4 [4] => 5 [5] => 6 [6] => 7 )
```

Answer (score 1):

under php 5.3 this should be really nice and convenient, because the array elements used by  array_reduce are interpreted as *mixed* rather than fixed as *integer*

so

```
print_r(array_reduce($test, 'array_merge'))
```

I haven't tested it -- no copy of 5.3 -- at least in *theory* that should do it.  Under <5.3 you'll get errors.

Note that this only merges the top level of array, unlike the solution using array_walk_recursive.

Comment: +1 for noticing the recent change to array_reduce. But, you need to supply an inital array to start with. array_reduce($aNestedArray, 'array_merge', array())

Answer (score 1):

```
$flattened = call_user_func_array('array_merge', $array);
```