# Show array without index key

Tags: php, arrays

```
print_r($arraydata);
```

I got output

Array ( [0] => vikas [1] => shirt [2] => cloth1 [3] => test [4] => shirt [5] => cloth2 [6] => avi )

i need to show array like that

$arr = array("vikas","shirt","cloth1","test","shirt","cloth2","avi");

Comment: [Similar topic here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2473844/how-to-get-array-of-values-from-an-associative-arrays)

Comment: `echo implode($arraydata, ',');`

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Use this :

```
echo '$arr = array("'.implode('", "', $arraydata).'");';
```

Comment: For those that like single quotes and not double quotes, and the new `[]` vs `array()`, here ya go: `echo "[" . implode("', '", $array) . "]";`

Answer (score 0):

If comma separation is necessary:

```
echo '$arr = array(';
foreach ($array as $key => $value) {
  if ($key > 0) echo ',';
  echo '"'.$value.'"';
}
echo ');';
```

Comment: @Mike That's very true, and Vincents answer above is better :)

Comment: not when you have 1.5 million rows and is close to get an out-of-memory crash, it isn't!