# PHP: How to print text continuously without using for/while loop

Tags: php

Without using a for/while loop or any kind of string repeat function and a single PHP
file, print out the text “All work and no play makes jack a dull boy” to the screen 200
times in a list
– Grade C: 15 lines of code
– Grade B: 10 lines of code
– Grade A: 7 lines of code
– Grade A*: 4 lines of code (VERY difficult)

– n.b. a “line” counts as a statement. Each closing brace must go on its own line, function calls on
their own line and function declarations on their own line. PHP tags

Comment: This isn't the place where people gives an answer to your homework.

Comment: This was an optional exercise set by our teacher and I was having problems solving it. So I posted it on here. Sorry.

Comment: @dexterb homework questions are actualy [okay](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334822/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions/334823#334823) on SO, although I agree, it should be made clear and the question itself should be revisited and fleshed out by OP.

Comment: @WilliamPerron yeah, it's okay to ask help for homework if and only if the OP has run out of ideas on solving the problem. When asking a question OP should provide the codes/pseudocodes/things the he at least have tried just to solve it.

Comment: @user9036433 no need to apologize :) a word of advice for the future: make sure to identify homework as such and clearly show what you have tried so far (ideally in the form of code)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use php's `array_fill()` method to fill an array 200 times with your data. http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-fill.php

After that you can use `implode()` to print that information out to the screen without using a loop. [Show array without index key](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11549707/show-array-without-index-key)

Of course, both of these methods will utilize a loop internally, but your code will be free of these.

This should work:

```
$a = array_fill(0, 200, 'banana');
echo implode($a, '<br />');
```